# Docker (or Python) - arguments passed to container are getting corrupted

Tags: python, linux, docker, encoding, character-encoding

I want to pass argument to Docker container, but it's getting corrupted:

```
$ docker run -it python python -c 'import os;import sys;print(sys.argv);print(os.fsencode(sys.argv[1]))' $'\xFF'
['-c', '�']
b'\xef\xbf\xbd'
```

I'm able to pass the data through Docker's stdin though:

```
$ echo -n $'\xFF' | docker run -i bash xxd
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Ark-kun could you explain why you set arg as binary data? `bash-3.2$ docker run -it python python -c "import os;import sys;print(sys.argv);print(os.fsencode(sys.argv[1]))" "one" "two" "three"` works fine.

Comment: @Ark-kun which terminal are you use? `bash-3.2$ docker run -it python python -c "import os;import sys;print(sys.argv);print(os.fsencode(sys.argv[1]))" "\xFF"`. works fine

Comment: Interesting. I use Debian 9 with standard Gnome Terminal v 3.26.0 and $ $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar You're calling it with `"\xFF"` which is just some string. I'm calling it with `$'\xFF'` which is a byte with code 255.